# Laplace differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody help me work out $2y''+y'-y=\mathrm{e}^{3t}$, y(0)=2 and y'(0)=0 with the method of Laplace? I got
\begin{align*}
Y(s)&=\frac{1}{(s-3)(2s^2+s-1)}+ \frac{2+4s}{(s-3)(2s^2+s-1)}\\
&=-\frac{4}{15}\frac{1}{2s-1}+\frac{1}{12}\frac{1}{s+1}+\frac{1}{20}\frac{1}{s-3}-\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{s+1}-\frac{16}{15}\frac{1}{2s-1}+\frac{7}{10}\frac{1}{s-3}\\
&=-\frac{2}{15}\mathrm{e}^{0.5t}+\frac{1}{12}\mathrm{e}^{-t}+\frac{1}{20}\mathrm{e}^{3t}-\frac{1}{6}\mathrm{e}^{-t}-\frac{8}{15}\mathrm{e}^{0.5t}+\frac{7}{10}\mathrm{e}^{3t}
\end{align*}
Is this correct?

Comment: welcome to MSE...please use latex and edit your post... i am sure even for you it would be difficult to read and most of the users don't even read this if it is in this way... please edit this by yourself....

Comment: What is your initial conditions?

Comment: y(0)=2 and y'(0)=0, so something goes wrong..

Comment: I think there is a typo? as the $\exp^{0.5t}$ terms in the final solution does not correspond to the laplace transformed terms. Also, as commented above what are the initial conditions? and finally, another tip try reducing the expressions first then manipulate. i.e. instead of what was given above, use $\frac{3+4s}{\left(s-3\right)\left(2s^{2}+s-1\right)}$ and the same for the following expressions.

Comment: I don't see the typo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Given:**

$$\tag 1 2 y''+ y'- y = e^{3t},~ y(0)=2, ~ y'(0)=0$$

Taking the Laplace Transform of $(1)$, we have:

$$\mathcal{L}(2 y''+ y'- y) = 2(s^2y(s) - sy(0)-y'0) + (sy(s)-y(0)) - y(s) = \dfrac{1}{s-3}$$

Using the initial conditions from $(1)$, this reduces to:

$$y(s)(2s^2 + s - 1) -4s - 2 = \dfrac{1}{s-3}$$

Solving for $y(s)$ and doing partial fraction expansions/simplifications yields:

$$y(s) = \dfrac{1}{20(s-3)} + \dfrac{3}{4(s+1)} + \dfrac{12}{5(2s-1)}$$

Now we want to find $\mathcal{L^{-1}}(y(s))$, yielding:

$$y(t) = \dfrac{1}{20}e^{3t} + \dfrac{3}{4}e^{-t} + \dfrac{6}{5}e^{t/2}$$

**Notes:**

- You can always easily validate $y(t)$ by plugging it back in to the DEQ and making sure it satisfies it.
- You can solve this problems using other methods like undetermined coefficients or variation of parameters.

Comment: Nice work and trailing notes! +1

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is $$ L(y)=\frac{-\exp(t)}{6}+\frac{\exp(3t)}{4}+\frac{2\exp(-.5t)}{21}.$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! When answering questions like this, you should provide the information you used to solve the problem or at least give hints on how to tackle the problem. I edited your post because you had some LaTeX code in there that shouldn't be there.